# iterate through column and only take item once

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

[image]
picture of sheet where I want to take the values from.

I have a sheet where I want to iterate through one column. Column "E" in sheet3. There are many duplicates in this column. It must take the value, and insert it into sheet1 column "C". It is important that I do not have duplicates in sheet1. I have tried to solve this problem using dictionaries. But I cannot get it to work. Can someone help me?

This is the code i got for now. I am stuck and can not get further.

```
Sub test()
    Const START_ROW = 11
    Const MAX_ROW = 40
    Const CODE_SHT1 = "C"
    Const CODE_SHT4 = "E"
    Const CVR_SHT4 = "C"
    Const CVR_SHT3 = "C"
    Const BROKER_SHT4 = "E"



    ' sheet 4  columns
    'C - Employer CVR MD
    'D - Employer name
    'E - broker code
    'F - Broker name
    '? Employer CVR CER

    Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long, iLastRow, iTargetRow As Long, iCopyRow As Long
    Dim msg As String, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim count As Long, countWB As Integer
    Dim WkSht_Src   As Worksheet
    Dim WkBk_Dest   As Workbook
    Dim WkSht_Dest  As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("BrokerSelect")
    Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("ContributionExceptionReport")
    Set ws4 = wb.Sheets("MasterData")



    Dim dict As Object, dictCVR As Object, dictBROKER As Object, sKey As String, ar As Variant
    Dim sCVR As String, arCVR As Variant
    Dim sBROKER As String, arBROKER As Variant

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictCVR = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictBROKER = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' Get broker code + broker name from sheet 3 and insert into sheet one
    iLastRow = ws4.Cells(Rows.count, BROKER_SHT4).End(xlUp).Row
    For iRow = 18 To iLastRow
    sKey = ws4.Cells(iRow, BROKER_SHT4)
    If dictBROKER.exist(sKey) Then
        dictBROKER(sKey) = dictBROKER(sKey) & ";" & iRow ' matched row on sheet 1
    Else
            dictBROKER(sKey) = iRow
        End If
        MsgBox (dict(sKey))

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: "cannot get it to work" - could you be more specific about your problem please? What exactly is not working?

Comment: Note that you forgot to declare `iLastRow As Long` and therefore `iLastRow` is of type `Variant`! Also there are a lot of variables declared that you never use. I recommend to tidy up. A good practice is to declare a variable as close as possible to their first use (instead of all of them at the top). So if you ever remove a variable you don't forget to remove the declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code has to be amended from (at least):

- a `Next` statament more (that by the end)
- use of `dict` instead of `dictBROKER`
- incorrect indentation (to have more chance to understand and control it)

so here it is after those changes

```
Sub Test()

    Const START_ROW = 11
    Const MAX_ROW = 40
    Const BROKER_SHT4 = "E"


    Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long, iLastRow, iTargetRow As Long, iCopyRow As Long
    Dim msg As String, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim count As Long, countWB As Integer
    Dim WkSht_Src   As Worksheet
    Dim WkBk_Dest   As Workbook
    Dim WkSht_Dest  As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("BrokerSelect")
    Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("ContributionExceptionReport")
    Set ws4 = wb.Sheets("MasterData")




    Dim dictBROKER As Object, dictCVR As Object, sKey As String, ar As Variant
    Dim sCVR As String, arCVR As Variant
    Dim sBROKER As String, arBROKER As Variant

    Set dictBROKER = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' Get broker code + broker name from sheet 3 and insert into sheet one
    iLastRow = ws4.Cells(Rows.count, BROKER_SHT4).End(xlUp).Row
    For iRow = 13 To iLastRow
        sKey = ws4.Cells(iRow, BROKER_SHT4)
        If dictBROKER.exists(sKey) Then
            dictBROKER(sKey) = dictBROKER(sKey) & ";" & iRow ' matched row on sheet 1
        Else
            dictBROKER(sKey) = iRow
        End If
        MsgBox (dictBROKER(sKey))
    Next

    ' add cvr records from sheet3 if any
    sBROKER = ws4.Cells(iCopyRow, BROKER_SHT4)
    If dictBROKER.exists(sBROKER) Then
         arBROKER = Split(dictBROKER(sBROKER), ";")
         For j = LBound(arBROKER) To UBound(arBROKER)
             If j > 0 Then iTargetRow = iTargetRow + 1

             ' copy col C to D
             iCopyRow = arBROKER(j)
             Debug.Print sBROKER, j, iCopyRow

         Next
    Else
        count = count + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes i have a lot of unseen code that i have not shown. However i do get an error at " If dictBROKER.exist(sKey) Then"  Run-time error '434': object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: ok. then insert my code suggestions in your actual code and if they do the trick you may mark my answer as accepted to direct future readers, too...

Comment: Hi @HTH. I think i got the post back.

Comment: ok. and does my solution work? (please note I edited `Exist` to `Exists`)

Comment: It seems like it stores the row number as key instead of the value in the cell. when i try to msgbox the dictBROKER(skey) i just get the row number value.. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: put a breakpoint at the `If dictBROKER.exists(sKey) Then` line (select the line and press F9) and once the code stops there, type in immediate window (ctrl-G to pop it out) `?sKey` and press return to see the actual value of `sKey`

Answer (score 0):

Sub exportSheet2()

```
Const START_ROW = 11
Const MAX_ROW = 40
Const BROKER_SHT4 = "E"

Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Long, iLastRow, iTargetRow As Long, iCopyRow As Long
Dim msg As String, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim count As Long, countWB As Integer
Dim WkSht_Src   As Worksheet
Dim WkBk_Dest   As Workbook
Dim WkSht_Dest  As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim r As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("sheet1")
Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("sheet3")
Set ws4 = wb.Sheets("sheet4")



Dim dict As Object, dictCVR As Object, sKey As String, ar As Variant
Dim sCVR As String, arCVR As Variant
Dim sBROKER As String, arBROKER As Variant

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dictCVR = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dictBROKER = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' Get broker code + broker name from sheet 3 and insert into sheet one
iLastRow = ws4.Cells(Rows.count, BROKER_SHT4).End(xlUp).Row
r = 11
For iRow = 13 To iLastRow
    sKey = ws4.Cells(iRow, BROKER_SHT4)
    If dictBROKER.exists(sKey) Then
        dictBROKER(sKey) = dictBROKER(sKey) & ";" & iRow ' matched row on sheet 1
    Else
        dictBROKER(sKey) = iRow

    ws1.Range("E" & r) = sKey
    ws1.Range("F" & r) = ws4.Cells(iRow, "F")
    r = r + 1
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Is this the solution?

Comment: Yes. I cannot put my own solution as "solution"at the moment.

Comment: and how is it different from mine?